# Will renaming a .html page to .php impact my websites google ranking?

Tags: php, html

It looks like I'm going to have change a .html file over to a .php file as I cannot parse PHP within the .html file. (I'm using IIS to handle PHP so I can't configure to parse PHP within html either)

Anyway, what I'm interested to know is if I change my .html over to .php page, how much will this impact my google rankings? Will it be like starting from scratch for that particular page and is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You need to use a "301 redirect" to maintain the rank for that page.

Watch the video here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93633

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially the answer to my question, to get round the issue I ended up using Rhinos suggestion above and used AJAX request to call back data from a separate php page.

Comment: Content served up via AJAX is not readable by Googlebot because the content is loaded AFTER the page has already been fetched. Because Googlebot doesn't run JavaScript your AJAX content will not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure IIS to treat .html files as PHP files. That way you can maintain the current file without any renaming, and internally it'll be treated as PHP code. The drawback is the extra overhead of parsing all your .html files, even if only one or two will be "php-ified":

https://serverfault.com/questions/118442/how-to-treat-any-file-as-php-in-windows-iis-7

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about this, and don't want to switch to `.php`, you could use Ajax requests to a PHP page, through JavaScript.

Comment: hmmmm yes I've done a little bit of this before using $get in jquery to fire off a request but not specifically with php. Do you happen to have any good links to resources on this?

Comment: A quick Google search pulled up [this](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html).  Looks like it would be easy to learn from, I don't know anything about the site.  Good luck!