# How to show/hide elements using PHP and how to send user to another page

Tags: php, html

I'm in the middle of sorting out the PHP for my contact form. What I'm trying to do is have an error message appear if the form isn't filled out. I have a div in my html with the error I want to show.

I know I can use 'echo' to display a message but I want it positioned exactly where I want it. I have seen a way of doing this, but it involves putting all the php code within the html file...and then renaming the file .php. I want to keep the bulk of the php code separate to the html.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="error">
    <p>
        Please fill out all fields.
    </p>
</div>
<form id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="65" tabindex="1"> <label for="name">Name</label> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" name="_replyto" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="30" tabindex="2"> <label for="email">Email</label> 
    </div>
    <div>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message..." maxlength="1000" tabindex="3"></textarea> <label for="message">Your Message</label> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" tabindex="4"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
// Check for form submission:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    /* The function takes one argument: a string.
    * The function returns a clean version of the string.
    * The clean version may be either an empty string or
    * just the removal of all newline characters.
    */
    function spam_scrubber($value) {

        // List of very bad values:
        $very_bad = array('to:', 'cc:', 'bcc:', 'content-type:', 'mime-version:', 'multipart-mixed:', 'content-transfer-encoding:');

        // If any of the very bad strings are in 
        // the submitted value, return an empty string:
        foreach ($very_bad as $v) {
            if (stripos($value, $v) !== false) return '';
        }

        // Replace any newline characters with spaces:
        $value = str_replace(array( "\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), ' ', $value);

        // Return the value:
        return trim($value);

    } // End of spam_scrubber() function.

    // Clean the form data:
    $scrubbed = array_map('spam_scrubber', $_POST);

    // Minimal form validation:
    if (!empty($scrubbed['name']) && !empty($scrubbed['email']) && !empty($scrubbed['comments']) ) {

        // Create the body:
        $body = "Name: {$scrubbed['name']}\n\nComments: {$scrubbed['comments']}";

        // Send the email:
        mail('example@email.com', 'Contact Form Submission', $body, "From: {$scrubbed['email']}");

        // Print a message:
        echo '<p><em>Thank you.</em></p>';

        // Clear $scrubbed (so that the form's not sticky):
        $scrubbed = array();

    } else {
        echo '<p style="font-weight: bold; color: #C00">Please fill out the form completely.</p>';
    }

} // End of main isset() IF
```

My php is in a file called contact.php and my html is in a file called contact.html.

I want to show the div with class error, if the form isn't complete.

I tried another way by adding this code to the html, replacing the current error div:

```
<span class="error">* <?php include 'contact.php'; echo $Err;?></span>
```

and this to the php file:

```
$Err = "Please fill out all fields";
```

It still didn't work. It's as if it can't read the code in the php file from the html file, even though I included it?

Another thing is, how would I go about sending the user to another html page once the form has been submitted? Is it done by replacing

```
// Print a message:
echo '<p><em>Thank you.</em></p>';
```

with

```
header('Location: nextpage.html');
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If you want the form page to have dynamic content, you're going to need to add PHP to it.

Comment: To redirect a user to a new page use a function like this:
`function to($url) {
    if(headers_sent()) {
        echo '<script>parent.window.location("'.$url.'")</script>';
    } else {
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit();
    }
}`

Comment: @wavemode I understand why I need PHP inside the html file but that would mean me changing the 'contact.html' to 'contact.php', and from what I've read, that affects things with google analytics.

Comment: @Forrest Not necessarily; you can instruct Apache (and presumably other servers, too) to treat a certain file as PHP (or other programming language), regardless of file name.

Comment: Re: redirection: header('Location: ...') is correct.

Comment: @ialar I have read that too. I have no idea how to go about that right now though. I'll have to look into it. If I can keep the .html file extension and treat it as PHP, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of using the javascript solution. first style the div to be `display:none;` then you can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('error')[0].style.display = "block";
```

when you wanna make it visible. Also JQuery Solution: (maybe incorrect, friends help plz!)

```
$('.error')[0].hide();
$('.error')[0].show();
```

You can also set speed/fade it using instructions here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp
Also for redirecting, yes you can replace them. Alternatively you can use JS solution too. replace

```
echo '<p><em>Thank you.</em></p>';
```

with:

```
echo '<p><em>Thank you.</em></p><script>location.replace("WHERE YOU WANNA GO!");</script>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: he asked to do it with php

Comment: we can do it with JQuery too!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand how the server processes PHP and HTML files. The server configuration tells it how to interpret files; some files are served as-is, some files are passed to a handler that executes them as a script, etc. In your server config, there will probably be a line that instructs the server to treat files with the extension `.php` as scripts to be executed using PHP. HTML files do not need to be executed; they are sent to the client, and the client's browser interprets the html, css, and js information to render a web page. Because HTML files are *not* executed as scripts, if you put code (perl, php, java, c++, smalltalk... whatever you want!) in the file, it will *not* be executed by the server, and it will not be executed by the browser *unless the browser has an interpreter for that language*, as is the case with HTML, CSS, and javascript. That is why the PHP in your HTML file is not being executed: unless you instruct your web server to interpret that file as a PHP script, it will treat it like a standard html file.

In your case, you want to present an error message to the user if the form validation fails. You also want to keep your code and your HTML file separate (which is a good habit to get into, IMHO!). This presents a problem because you really need to alter the content of the HTML page to include an error message, but the HTML page is essentially static. You could redirect users to another page with the same content, but an error message at the top of the page, but that's a rather ugly solution. You could also use javascript to do the form validation and present the user with an error message if their form submission is invalid, but anyone who has JS turned off will be able to bypass that check.

The most flexible solution for your problem is to use a template system that allows you to customise your page content but keep your PHP code free from HTML. There are a number of PHP template systems out there; google will turn up plenty for you. The templates contain variables that you can set in your PHP script and use in the template; the template engine then parses the templates, interpolates the variables, and outputs the result.

In your case, you could set up your form to display an error message at the top of the form and perhaps to highlight the fields that have been incorrectly filled.

Here is an example using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net), a popular, flexible template system:

```
include('Smarty.class.php');

// create object
$smarty = new Smarty;

if (! empty($_POST)) {
    // validate your form input
    ...
    // Minimal form validation:
    if (!empty($scrubbed['name']) && !empty($scrubbed['email']) && !empty($scrubbed['comments']) ) {
        // send your email
        // redirect user to a thank you page
        header("Location: thankyou.html");
    }
    else {
        // sets a variable $error in the template
        $smarty->assign('error', 'Please fill out the form completely');
    }
}

// display it
$smarty->display('form.tpl');
```

The template file, `form.tpl`, should contain your standard form plus any sections that you want added in case of error. Here's a snippet from an example `form.tpl` file:

```
<h2>Contact me!</h2>
{if isset($error)}
<div class="error">
    <p>
        {$error}
    </p>
</div>
{/if}

<form id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
(etc.)
```

output if contact.php detects an error:

```
<h2>Contact me!</h2>
<div class="error">
    <p>
        Please fill out the form completely
    </p>
</p>
<form id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
(etc.)
```

output if there is no error (i.e. the form has not been filled in):

```
<h2>Contact me!</h2>
<form id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
(etc.)
```

This is a very basic example of what templates can do. I hope that has clarified things a little and given you a glimpse into the wonderful world of HTML templates.

Comment: Thanks very much for this detailed answer. Would this mean that I can keep my html page as a .html file rather than changing it to a .php file?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. You need to turn contact.html into an .php file aswell in order to use php code.
Consider naming your contact.php > contact.script.php, and rename contact.html to contact.php.
Then, in your php code you could do something like this:

**contact.script.php**

```
if((!empty($scrubbed['name']) && !empty($scrubbed['email']) && !empty($scrubbed['comments']) ) {
    ...
    $message = 'Thank you.';
} else {
#   put your error message into the same variable
    $message =  'Please fill out the form completely.';
}
```

**contact.php:**

```
/* at the very beginning of your code */
include 'path/to/contact.script.php';
/* Then, wherever you would like to show the message just add this at the end: */
<?=$message?>  //  this will echo out the message (same as <?php echo $message; ?> - as in:

<div class="error"><p><?=$message?></p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however I've read that turning a .html file into a .php file affects google analytics? Here is the source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396531/will-renaming-a-html-page-to-php-impact-my-websites-google-ranking

Comment: That's true since when you renaming your file, it would be detected as a new document that google crawles. As they stated, you can do a 301 (permanent redirect) to keep the ranking. This means that you need to keep your existing contact.html file, and when a user tries to access it, you they're sent to your new contact.php. This should be done in .htaccess by the way...

Comment: Ok thanks. This is completely new to me..I'll have to look into how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $ta;?>">

<div id="content" style="display:<?php echo $ta==2 ? 'block':'none' ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it